# security issue in connecting to a database in using jdbc

Tags: java, sql, security, jdbc

I have created a java application which connects with the sql database using jdbc. Its a swing application. The code to connect to the database is in one of the files of the project. The username and password to the sql server is hardcoded in there.

I want a solution for this so that I connect to the server(one of the computers on the network having the database ) without directly writing the password in the application, rather it should read from some file on the server.How to do it ?

Again, a security problem comes here that i will have to provide the file name in the application. Since a jar file can easily be decompiled to obtain the source code, anyone can see the name of the file and access it.

How to solve this security issue ?

Comment: server means SQL server?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your concerns, but there is no way to achieve **exactly** what you want. If the application has to connect with the database, it has to "know" the access credentials.

"Obfuscation" techniques (like "encrypt the password and decrypt on the fly" or "pull the password from somewhere else") are just palliatives that would move the problem elsewhere.

You should consider adding a layer of abstraction. Your application should access **remote web services** that just provide the CRUD functionalities your application needs, applying the [Principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). Modern client-server architectures are designed in such a way that the "rich client" (like your Swing application) doesn't directly interact with the DBMS. Yes, it is slower, but it is more safe and scalable. Also, your rich client becomes "less rich" (it does not implement business logic) thus avoiding the need to update it if you change a table, for example.

Using a web service also enables you to *enforce complex constraints*. For example, take an online help desk. A common rule is that you cannot post messages on closed tickets. How do you enforce that in a DBMS? If I can login to your DBMS, I can post as many messages as I want for a ticket that has the `closed` attribute set to `1`: nothing will enforce the constraint unless some cumbersome CHECK clause that isn't even supported in some DBMS.

**Hide your DB!**

Consider REST as a lightweight alternative to SOAP for web services. In Java you can create REST servers and clients in a snap using [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/).

Comment: don't you think that adding some remote web service will also take problem to some other level?

Comment: Sure. But you can actually shrink the risk to the least possible: security policies are handled server-side, and not client-side. Many old rich clients enforce policies on the client-side, because a SQL server is not able to handle complex restrictions, even playing with permissions. If you reverse engineer the client, you can get raw access to DBMS and just ignore your restrictions.

Comment: but still you will have to provide credentials from client side because you can't let anybody connect to your database using web interface.

Comment: I think, REST or SOAP do not solve the hardcoded credentials problem on they own - you still need to authenticate. Or, if they do, then how?

Comment: Yes, you have to authenticate. But the attack surface decreases: **this is the point**. With a web service you can actually enforce very tight constraints of what is seen from the outside. You don't even show the names of the tables and the structure of the DB. There's less room for playing with SQL. Think about it. Ask an Enterprise to get access to their Oracle database, even read-only. They'll laugh at you and send you a WSDL.

Comment: Signing your requests to the API with a shared secret can serve as authentication.

Comment: It'll save you from password-based authentication, but still the application can be manipulated in order to craft any message you want and sign it with the shared secret. No need to know what the shared secret is.

Comment: For high security you can use WS-Security standards family, for low security you can implement password authentication, and publish service on HTTPS endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that credentials should not be hardcoded in the code. This stays true also for web service credentials.

I propose to ask for the username password from the user, one time (on first start) or maybe even periodically (say monthly). Then you could save the credentials in the user home directory, [setting permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadable%28boolean,%20boolean%29) so that only owner can access them (let OS to care about security). Most of web servers that require authentication work more or less along these lines.

Comment: how the user will know the database password and username. He is not suppose to.

Comment: Do you mean, knowing database credentials would give possibility to do something that the user cannot do just because he runs your program? If so, it may be really good to put a REST API in between, limiting actions to that is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> I want a solution for this so that I connect to the server(one of the
>   computers on the network having the datbase ) without directly writing
>   the password in the application, rather it should read from some file
>   on the server

Hope you did not mean server as DB server because first to access the password from db server, you need to access db server for which you need pwd somewhere at server side(where application is deployed) :).Ideally,you should provide the credentials in property file  where application is deployed. This is the way its generally done

Regarding security one way i can think of is you can write the program that will generate the credentials in property file and also mail to db admin to change the credentials at some point of time.